# Get unique values from JSON with out looping

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I am having a array in the format:

```
const resultData = [
  [1, 2, 'a', 'b'],
  [1, 4, 'c', 'f'],
  [2, 5, 'a', 'b'],
  [1, 2, 'c', 'd'],
  [9, 3, 'c', 'f'],
  [5, 4, 'f', 'g']
]
```

and I am trying to convert in in the format:

```
[{
  value: "a,b",
  data: [
    [1, 2],
    [2, 5]
  ]
}, {
  value: "c,f",
  data: [
    [1, 4],
    [9, 3]
  ]
}, {
  value: "c,d",
  data: [
    [1, 2]
  ]
}, {
  value: "f,g",
  data: [
    [5, 4]
  ]
}]
```

I am using a map currently with a for loop:

```
var mapp = new Map;
_.each(resultData, item => {
  var x = item.col.slice(2);
  if (mapp.has(x.toString())) {
    var temp = mapp.get(x.toString());
    temp.push([item.col[0], item.col[1]]);
    mapp.set(x.toString(), temp);
  } else {
    var valuesArray = [];
    valuesArray.push([item.col[0], item.col[1]])
    mapp.set(x.toString(), valuesArray);
  }
});
```

I am having a huge data set. Is there a possible way to do it without a loop or any other method?

Comment: What do you mean by *"without a loop"*? Does your current code produce expected results?

Comment: What is the problem with your current method that you are trying to solve?

Comment: please add valid `resultData`.

Comment: the short answer is absolutely not. It's not possible to convert this data set without looping through at least once.

Comment: I am achieving the result but it is taking a lot of time for around 1 million records, i am trying to reduce the time @charlietfl

Comment: @Ram the is the unfortunate downside to the Javascript event loop. Processing 1 million records will block all other execution until its complete. If this is an issue, you will need to think of a better application architecture that provides the data in the format you need before you manipulate it. Possibly your own API Server or a WebWorker that will process the data in the background. Without knowing more about your application it's hard to determine your needs, but you have already solved the formatting problem and while it can be done other ways, they will all be of the same performance.

Comment: @sctskw Not if it is executed in a web/node worker process or a [node thread](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html).

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Thank you. You clearly did not read my comment in it's entirety.

Answer (score 0):

I would use reduce to generate the results:

1. check if the key values already exists
2. If it does, append the new items to the data array
3. If it does not, create the new object with the data

```js
const resultData = [
  [1, 2, 'a', 'b'],
  [1, 4, 'c', 'f'],
  [2, 5, 'a', 'b'],
  [1, 2, 'c', 'd'],
  [9, 3, 'c', 'f'],
  [5, 4, 'f', 'g']
]

let result = resultData.reduce((arr, itm) => {
  let value = itm[2] + ',' + itm[3]
  let item = arr.find(i => i.value == value)
  if (!item) arr.push({ value, data: [[itm[0], itm[1]]] })
  else item.data.push([itm[0], itm[1]])
  return arr
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `reduce` and `Object.values` method like below

```js
const resultData = [[1,2,'a','b'],[1,4,'c','f'],[2,5,'a','b'],[1,2,'c','d'],[9,3,'c','f'],[5,4,'f','g']]

const res = resultData.reduce((acc, item) => {
   const key = item.slice(2).join();
   const value = item.slice(0, 2);
   
   if(!acc[key]) {
      acc[key] = {value: key, data: [value]};
   } else {
      acc[key] = {...acc[key], data: [...acc[key].data, value]}  
   }
   return acc;
}, {});

console.log(Object.values(res));
```

Comment: You've definitely proposed a cleaner way of processing the data, but this does not solve the time problem he's asking unfortunately. In fact, it will likely be worse since you're looping twice with the extra use of Object.values

Answer (score 0):

Javascript arrays have a .map method:

```
var newArray = resultData.map(function(arrayMember){

    var objectToReturn = {};

    objectToReturn['value'] = arrayMember; // add other transformations

    return objectToReturn;

}); // map
```

Comment: You could also run an experiment where you stringify the array (or chunks of the array at a time) and the use regex text replace to transform, then parse the transformed strings back to js. Maybe faster?

Comment: Totally missed you're using a Map object. I saw this online: Just use Array.from(map, ([key, value]) => value)

Answer (score 0):

another solution:

```
const res = _.chain(resultData)
    .groupBy(item => _.takeRight(item, 2).join(','))
    .mapValues((items, value) => ({
        value,
        data: _.map(items, arr => _.take(arr, 2))
    }))
    .values() 
    .value();
```